# get the current element in (inline function in JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the element itself through making a function in the div itself  I want when someone clicks on the current Element the Element should be deleted by fading in pure JavaScript I have searched on the internet but not getting the answer there are many similar questions on Stack Overflow but none of them giving me the combined answer(Like getting current element through Js in (inline function)).
So anyone can help me

```html
<div style="width: 100px;height: 100px;background:red;" onclick="(function(ele){
        console.log('helo')
        console.log(ele.currentTarget)})();">
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are invoking the onclick callback immediately, but there is no click event so of course it's undefined. Voting to close as "not reproducible or caused by typo".

Comment: @DrewReese it's closed but thing is that  I want the current Element through the inline function I have searched but there is not similar question like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

I added an `id` to your `div` which can be accessed through the `getElementById`.

```html
<div id='hello' style="width: 100px;height: 100px;background:red;" onclick="
    (
        function() {
            document.getElementById('hello').style.opacity = 0;
            document.getElementById('hello').style.transition = '0.5s';
        }
    )();">
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this answer but there is no way to do this through inline function in Js and may I know why your answer and your question is downvoted

Comment: Arceno if this question seems help full you can upvote this

Comment: I updated the code. That should be what you're looking for. @ShayanKanwal

Comment: @Prosey Arceno can you please answer my other Javascript question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67433538/settimeout-animation-problem-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment119191753_67433538 it seems complex